# MobileFirst 7 Error FWLSE3010E: A database error was detected when opening the mobile first console

Tags: mysql, ibm-mobilefirst, websphere, mobilefirst-server

Although we can login to the MySQL workbench the JDBC connection drops after a period of time of it working.

We get this error after restarting the JVM.

> [2/28/17 9:16:29:764 GMT] 0000009d webapp        E
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E:
>   [Servlet Error]-[ManagementServlet]: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to open data base.     at
>   com.ibm.worklight.dataaccess.datastore.DataStoreUtil.getDataStore(DataStoreUtil.java:401)
>     at
>   com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.BaseService.getDataStore(BaseService.java:240)
>     at
>   com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.BaseService.createEntityManager(BaseService.java:261)
>     at
>   com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.BaseService.auditStart(BaseService.java:713)
>     at
>   com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.BaseService.auditStart(BaseService.java:684)
>     at
>   com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.BaseService.auditStart(BaseService.java:661)
>     at
>   com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.ManagementService.loginAudit(ManagementService.java:132)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.InvokeMethodHandler.handleRequest(InvokeMethodHandler.java:63)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:33)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.CreateInvocationParametersHandler.handleRequest(CreateInvocationParametersHandler.java:54)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:34)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceMethod(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:110)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindRootResourceHandler.handleRequest(FindRootResourceHandler.java:95)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.HeadMethodHandler.handleRequest(HeadMethodHandler.java:53)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.OptionsMethodHandler.handleRequest(OptionsMethodHandler.java:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.SearchResultHandler.handleRequest(SearchResultHandler.java:33)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.ResourceInvocation.handleRequest(ResourceInvocation.java:92)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Requests.handleRequest(Requests.java:76)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.run(AbstractHandlersChain.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithoutFaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:207)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:154)
>     at
>   org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:133)
>     at
>   com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:43)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1232)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:781)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:480)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
>     at
>   com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.RestFilter.doFilter(RestFilter.java:61)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
>     at
>   com.ibm.worklight.admin.common.filter.HSTSFilter.doFilter(HSTSFilter.java:110)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3928)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1007)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
>     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)   at
>   com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)     at
>   com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1881) Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: FWLSE3010E: A database error was detected.
>
> When I test the connection of the data source in websphere I get this
>   error.
>
> The test connection operation failed for data source Worklight
>   database worklightDB on server nodeagent at node Node01 with the
>   following exception: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user
>   '**SuperUser**'@'localhost' (using password: YES) DSRA0010E: SQL State
>   = 28000, Error Code = 1,045. View JVM logs for further details.

The password is set correctly as I am able to Login to the MySQL workbench with it and it is also working on two other JVMs.

Comment: Being able to login to MySQL workbench and a remote JVM connecting to MySQL instance might need different configurations. Have you verified the "Users and privileges" section under management to see if the login is allowed

Comment: Thanks for the response, we are using the user on two other JVMs and I know if I redeploy the configuration it will work again. It seems like it is just forgetting the connection details.

Comment: This JVM where you see the issue, is it on a different physical machine?

Comment: No they are all on the same machine